# Account for empty rows when transferring data to fixed layout

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on this data transfer project for the past week and I found the last issue. I have the following code which is in a template named ALPHA. This macro opens 4 workbooks in the background (Location1,2,3,4) and copies certain cells and paste them in ALPHA. Now currently it does the following:

It paste the data in the next empty row in C,F,I, and L as shown

[image: ALPHA]

The Problem is not all test (Location files) have the 6th data, So if a cell is left blank the data for the 2nd result from the next test ends up in the Row1 when it should be in Row2. This happens because if the C8 in the picture is blank then the code paste the next results starting there, and the data is shifted one up. I need the code to find next empty row but only if the empty row is in a different section (Lables ROW1, ROW2, etc.) How can I do this? Thanks.

Note: The values under Location labels in the picture come from each Location workbook

Code:

```
Sub DataTransfer()

Const FPATH As String = "C:\Users\bsmallwood\Desktop\FRF_Location_Data\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim shtAlpha As Worksheet 'Template
Dim locs, loc
Dim rngDest As Range

locs = Array("location1.xlsm", "location2.xlsm", _
             "location3.xlsm", "location4.xlsm")

Set shtAlpha = Workbooks("FRF_Data_Sheet_Template.xlsm").Sheets("DataInput")

'set the first data block destination
Set rngDest = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(5, 3)

For Each loc In locs

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FPATH & loc, ReadOnly:=True)

    rngDest.Value = wb.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value

    wb.Close False

    Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 3) 'move over to the right 3 cols

Next loc

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula to calculate the next starting point. In your case, your sections start at rows 4, 9, 14, 19, etc. So you could use the following formula:

```
intLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 1) Mod 5
```

That will take your last row and bump it up to the start of the next section. For example:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ intLast ║ intNext ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ 0       ║ 4       ║
║ 1       ║ 4       ║
║ 2       ║ 4       ║
║ 3       ║ 4       ║
║ 4       ║ 9       ║
║ 5       ║ 9       ║
║ 6       ║ 9       ║
║ 7       ║ 9       ║
║ 8       ║ 9       ║
║ 9       ║ 14      ║
║ 10      ║ 14      ║
║ 11      ║ 14      ║
║ ...     ║ ...     ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

**Edit**, with respect to comments:

So, in your code, you'd need to change:

```
shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(5, 3)
```

To:

```
intLast = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 1) Mod 5
Set rngDest = shtAlpha.Cells(intNext, "C").Resize(5, 3)
```

Comment: That's a more elegant solution than the one I was arriving at.

Comment: so replace `Set rngDest = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(5, 3)` with that?

Comment: @Duraholiday - I've added an edit to show what you'd need to change.

Comment: Im sorry if this is a stupid question but do I need the table.... other wise it gives me the Error variable not defined `intlast`

Comment: @Duraholiday - Not a stupid question. You just need to declare the new variables. I omitted that in my answer. `Dim intLast As Long, intNext As Long`.

Comment: Should I `Dim rngDest As Range` too? Its not declared either. I get an error code type mismatch `intLast = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)`

Comment: It looks like you already have `rngDest` declared from what I can see. As for the type mismatch, I noticed that shortly after posting and corrected the code. Take a look at the update above. It should end in `.Row`.

Comment: Had to `Dim rngDest As Range` and then what you gave me worked! Thank you, and thanks for being patient, im not the best at this kinda stuff haha.

Comment: OK so i changed my section size from 5 rows to 19 rows, I tried to change the numbers but its not working. How do you adjust it?

Comment: Assuming your first section still starts on row 4, your new formula would be: `intLast + 19 - (intLast + 15) Mod 19`.

Comment: that worked, I guess i just dont understand the what the code is actually doing, why is it intlast + 15?

Comment: Because of your offset. Your first section doesn't start at `0`. It starts at `4`. So `(intLast + 15) Mod 19` accounts for that `4` row offset (`19 - 15`), just like in our original formula (`5 - 1`).

Comment: ohh gotch ya. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bond One last thing, What if i wanted to implement this to columns instead of rows, on a different VBA? (To paste to next empty column to the right) would this work?                                                                                             `intLast = Omega.Cells(Columns.Count, "1").End(xlRight).Column
                            intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 5) Mod 5
                            Set rngDest = Omega.Cells(intNext, "A").Resize(30000, 3)`  I tried to just flip-flop things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i'm looking at this right, but if your goal is what i'm thinking, this whole thing can be accomplished by querying the other spreadsheets, by importing external data. I'm using Excel 2003, in which the process would be (do this 4 times with each of the sheets): Data --> Import External Data --> New Database Query --> Excel Files.  From there you would select your sheet, and add criteria through MS Query (remove blanks, etc).  Then indicate where you would like the data placed. (from your screenshot C3,F3,I3,L3 respectively if you include column headers in the 4 queries).  Set data range properties to refresh on open.  If i follow you right, this will accomplish the same thing actually without any macros at all.